# ASP.NET Core Jwt 401 Unauthorized. Policy auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I've stacked on a problem with jwt. I have created a working jwt factory that returns valid tokens, for example:
[image]

And I've added policy to the Startup:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim("rol", "api_access"));
    });
```

Nevertheless I can't pass through the Authorize attribute with my valid token (Please notice that the the only requirement is token to have "rol":"api_access"):

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
...
```

I test my application with postman:
[image]

So it seems that Authorize is blocking the request but I don't understand the reason of it. Hope you can help me.

Some code that may be useful:
Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA213sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH"; // todo: get this from somewhere secure
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PharmaContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddDbContext<PharmaContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Pharma")));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();
        services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();


        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });


        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        });

        // api user claim policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
        });

        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
        {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<PharmaContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddAutoMapper();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(
                    async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    });
            });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

JwtFactory:

```
public class JwtFactory : IJwtFactory
    {
        private readonly JwtIssuerOptions _jwtOptions;

        public JwtFactory(IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtOptions)
        {
            _jwtOptions = jwtOptions.Value;
            ThrowIfInvalidOptions(_jwtOptions);
        }

        public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            var claims = new[]
         {
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                 identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol),
                 identity.FindFirst(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id)
             };

            // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
                audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
                expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
                signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            return encodedJwt;
        }

        public ClaimsIdentity GenerateClaimsIdentity(string userName, string id)
        {
            return new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Token"), new[]
            {
                new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, id),
                new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess)
            });
        }

        /// <returns>Date converted to seconds since Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970, midnight UTC).</returns>
        private static long ToUnixEpochDate(DateTime date)
          => (long)Math.Round((date.ToUniversalTime() -
                               new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero))
                              .TotalSeconds);

        private static void ThrowIfInvalidOptions(JwtIssuerOptions options)
        {
            if (options == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

            if (options.ValidFor <= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Must be a non-zero TimeSpan.", nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.ValidFor));
            }

            if (options.SigningCredentials == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.SigningCredentials));
            }

            if (options.JtiGenerator == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.JtiGenerator));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute above your controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = "ApiUser")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    ...methods here...
}
```

Comment: It works. I think I can add AuthenticationSchemes to Startup somehow, can I?

Comment: @Storm, add `policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` when you add your policy and require claims